# I want to upload an html document to SharePoint but dont have SharePoint Designer

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, html-form-web-part

I have some HTML script that basically displays a countdown clock in a Web Part on SharePoint 2013.  We don't have SharePoint Designer and uploading `.html` documents are blocked from our implementation.

Is there any way around this?

**Here is the script I want to upload.**

```
<script language="JavaScript">
TargetDate = "05/25/2018 0:00 AM";
BackColor = "palegreen";
ForeColor = "navy";
CountActive = true;
CountStepper = -1;
LeadingZero = true;
DisplayFormat = "%%D%% Days, %%H%% Hours, %%M%% Minutes, %%S%% Seconds.";
FinishMessage = "It is finally here!";
</script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="//scripts.hashemian.com/js/countdown.js"></script>
```

Comment: Simply add your code to script editor webpart in your SharePoint page

Comment: I'm going add my own answer here - but you can upload a document with the syntax <filename>.html.txt.

Comment: the insert a CEWP and link to this new document.  IT WORKSSSS

Comment: it's the same method, just add SEWP with your code , instead of upload this page file then add a link to CEWP, the main job of script editor webpart is to hold script! do you try it to know how much it simple and efficient than CEWP! especially you are using SP 2013!

Comment: I personally find the linked file in CEWP option to be more helpful for code I might update multiple times. That way I don't have to roll back version history on my entire page to reference the old code, in case I've changed other page elements as well in the interim.

Comment: @BrendanW Agree, but what's the main job of Script Editor Web Part in your opinion, where it added as a new web part in SP 2013 and still there in SP 2016? regarding version with SEWP you can do that by closing the current script with old code and add a new SEWP with your new code!

Comment: @M.Qassas I agree SEWP has its merits as well :) I use it frequently for small changes like a CSS tweak on a specific page. But I also have larger scripts for things like custom web parts which I find easier to manage as separate files linked through CEWP with their own version control.

Comment: Okay so we agree :) but do you think the above script is larger scripts ?! we answer here based on question requirement and the current situation! Thank you so much for this valuable conversation :)

Answer (score 3):

You can easily add your script within `Script Editor Web Part` in your SharePointPage as the following:

- Edit your page.
- Add `Script Editor Web Part`.

[image]

- Edit Snippet.
- Add your code script.

[image]

- Click insert, Stop page editing.

**Output**

[image]